# Kivy unable to access an id within the class of a kv file

Tags: python, kivy

So I am trying to put a table that I have rendered into a BoxLayout but somehow it seems to be unable to access it, I'm not sure on how to access it. I created a class itemlist(BoxLayout) and within it is a function to run it. I used the self.ids.content which is linked to the id:content in the kv file but somehow I am unable to access it. I either get a `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' error` (the code as shown) or it doesn't run at all (if i remove the itemlist class from the kv)

**PYTHON CODE**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import sqlite3
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from collections import OrderedDict
from datatable import DataTable
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MainWindow(Screen):
    amount=ObjectProperty(None)
    category=ObjectProperty(None)
    message=ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_expense(self):

        date = str(datetime.now())
        conn = sqlite3.connect("expenditure.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO expenses (amount,category,message,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)""", (self.amount.text,self.category.text,self.message.text,date))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        self.amount.text=""
        self.category.text=""
        self.message.text=""

    def success(self):
        pop = Popup(title='Success!',
                  content=Label(text='Successfully added expense!'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        pop.open()






class SecondWindow(Screen):
    searched=ObjectProperty(None)
    class itemlist(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)

            content = self.ids.content
            entry = self.get_items()
            entrytable = DataTable(table=entry)
            content.add_widget(entrytable)


        def get_items(self):    
            conn = sqlite3.connect("expenditure.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()

            _entries = OrderedDict(
                amountlist = {},
                categorylist = {},
                messagelist = {},
                datelist = {} 
            )
            amountlist = []
            categorylist = []
            messagelist = []
            datelist = []
            sql = ("SELECT * FROM expenses;")
            cur.execute(sql)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for amt,cat,price,dt in rows:
                amountlist.append(amt)
                categorylist.append(cat)
                messagelist.append(price)
                datelist.append(dt)
            entrynum = len(amountlist)
            idx = 0
            while idx < entrynum:
                _entries['amountlist'][idx] = amountlist[idx]
                _entries['categorylist'][idx] = categorylist[idx]
                _entries['messagelist'][idx] = messagelist[idx]
                _entries['datelist'][idx] = datelist[idx]

                idx +=1

            return _entries





class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")



def view(category=None):

    conn = db.connect("expenditure.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if category:
        sql = '''
        select * from expenses where category = '{}'
        '''.format(category)
        sql2 = '''
        select sum(amount) from expenses where category = '{}'
        '''.format(category)
    else:
        sql = '''
        select * from expenses
        '''.format(category)
        sql2 = '''
        select sum(amount) from expenses
        '''.format(category)
    cur.execute(sql)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute(sql2)
    total_amount = cur.fetchone()[0]

    return total_amount, results

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    conn = sqlite3.connect("expenditure.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = '''
    create table if not exists expenses (
        amount number,
        category string,
        message string,
        date string
        )
    '''
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**KV Code**

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    amount : amt
    category : ctgry
    message : msg

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Input your expenditure"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "amount: "

            TextInput:
                id: amt
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Category: "

            TextInput:
                id:ctgry
                multiline:False  
            Label:
                text: "Message: "

            TextInput:
                id:msg
                multiline:False               

            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_press:root.add_expense()
                on_release:root.success()

            Button:
                text: "See your items"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    searched : categorysearch
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            Label:
                text: "Category: "

            TextInput:
                id:categorysearch
                multiline:False
            Button:
                text: "Search category"


        itemlist:
            BoxLayout:
                id:content





        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

I'm not sure if the issue is due to the class level or something. if it is how to fix it? Thank you!

Edit: I have also tried removing the `class itemlist(BoxLayout)` to make it directly under `secondwindow` and made minor adjustments to the kv file but it still doesn't work. I have no other idea on how to approach this.

Comment: In the scenario I remove the itemlist from the kv file leaving BoxLayout: id:content, program would run but the function wouldn't run I'm not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access the `ids` incorrectly and at the wrong time. The `ids` are defined for the `Widget` that is the root of the `kv` rule. So the `content` `id` is defined in the `ids` of `SecondWindow`. Your code is trying to access the `ids` of `itemList`, which will not have any `ids`. You are also trying to access the `ids` before they are defined. The `ids` are defined when the root `Widget` of the rule is completely constructed, but you are accessing them in the `__init__()` method of the `itemList` class (too early).

Comment: Also, you are defining `itemList` as extending `BoxLayout`, then in the `kv`, you are adding a `BoxLayout` to the `itemList`. So you are effectively adding a `BoxLayout` to a `BoxLayout`. Is that your intention? And your `itemList` class is an `Inner` class of `SecondWindow` (by indentation). Is that also your intention?

Comment: @JohnAnderson my intention is to add a BoxLayout within the SecondWindow where I can display the table. I had tried to directly do ```itemlist: id:content``` but it gave me an error  which is why I left it with a ```BoxLayout``` within the  ```itemlist``` so I'm not sure how to solve this solution. How would I find a way to solve the issue u said above?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `datatable` that you are using, so I couldn't completely run your code. In spite of that problem, I have some suggested changes to your code to make it work as I believe you want. First, I changed the indentation of your `itemList` class definition so that it is not an inner class of `SecondWindow`. Like this:

```
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    searched=ObjectProperty(None)


class itemlist(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #content = self.ids.content  # not needed, this is the container
        entry = self.get_items()
        entrytable = DataTable(table=entry)
        #content.add_widget(entrytable)  # replaced with self.add_widget()
        self.add_widget(entrytable)


    def get_items(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("expenditure.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        _entries = OrderedDict(
            amountlist = {},
            categorylist = {},
            messagelist = {},
            datelist = {}
        )
        amountlist = []
        categorylist = []
        messagelist = []
        datelist = []
        sql = ("SELECT * FROM expenses;")
        cur.execute(sql)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for amt,cat,price,dt in rows:
            amountlist.append(amt)
            categorylist.append(cat)
            messagelist.append(price)
            datelist.append(dt)
        entrynum = len(amountlist)
        idx = 0
        while idx < entrynum:
            _entries['amountlist'][idx] = amountlist[idx]
            _entries['categorylist'][idx] = categorylist[idx]
            _entries['messagelist'][idx] = messagelist[idx]
            _entries['datelist'][idx] = datelist[idx]

            idx +=1

        return _entries
```

I have modified the `__init__()` method. Since the `itemList` is the `BoxLayout`, you don't need to query the `ids`, just use `self`.

I also removed the extra `BoxLayout` from your `kv`, so your `SecondWindow` rule in `kv` now looks like:

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    searched : categorysearch
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            Label:
                text: "Category: "

            TextInput:
                id:categorysearch
                multiline:False
            Button:
                text: "Search category"

        itemlist:
            id:content

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

And the `id: content` is not needed for your posted code, so that can also be removed.